# Error 404 with Java HttpClient

Tags: java

I am using Java HttpClient package to make http requests. But I am getting 404. When I try the same request with curl, it works fine. Here's the curl request -

`curl -i -X POST http://api/endpoint -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d 'content'`

Here's the java code that I am using to implement the above curl request -

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://api/endpoint");
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

post.setEntity(new StringEntity(content));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
logger.info("Response Code : "
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
logger.info("Response details "+result);
```

I see error 404 NOT FOUND when I run this java code. What could the problem be?

Comment: The 2 tests are not the same, with HttpClient you set the 'Accept' HTTP header. Please add this to the curl just to be sure is the same.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini I removed it from the java code. Still getting 404 while curl works

Comment: Are you under a proxy?

Comment: @MarioSantini I am facing the same and under the Squid proxy. Any help or pointers please?

Comment: @ROCKY if you have to go through a proxy, you just need to configure the connection to handle it. Here you can find a simple example, but you can do it on any kind of lib in Java https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_httpclient/apache_httpclient_using_proxy.htm

Answer (score 1):

Remove  *post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");*

Comment: works flawlessly! can also add wildcard content type